# How to create CustomDialogBox with Custom Listview

Tags: java, android, android-listview, customdialog

I am trying to create an app where if I click on a button then a CustomDialogbox will appear which will contain a Listvew and the ListItems will have specific design which I have already created.
I have created the listview but I am unable to join it with my CustomDialogbox .
Please help me how to implement it.
Here is my so far code:

MainActivity.java:

```
public class Test1101 extends Activity {

final Context context = this;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_test1101);



    Button button= (Button)findViewById(R.id.buttonShowCustomDialog);
    button.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View arg0) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

            final Dialog dialog=new Dialog(context);
            dialog.setContentView(R.layout.list);
            ListView lv = (ListView ) dialog.findViewById(R.id.listV_main);
            dialog.setCancelable(true);
            dialog.setTitle("Groups");



                ArrayList<ItemDetails> results = new ArrayList<ItemDetails>();

                ItemDetails item_details = new ItemDetails();
                item_details.setName("Bolly Talks");
                item_details.setImageNumber(1);
                results.add(item_details);

                item_details = new ItemDetails();
                item_details.setName("Politics");
                item_details.setImageNumber(2);
                results.add(item_details);

                item_details = new ItemDetails();
                item_details.setName("Controversies");
                item_details.setImageNumber(3);
                results.add(item_details);

                item_details = new ItemDetails();
                item_details.setName("Sports");
                item_details.setImageNumber(4);
                results.add(item_details);

                item_details = new ItemDetails();
                item_details.setName("Spiritual");
                item_details.setImageNumber(5);
                results.add(item_details);

                item_details = new ItemDetails();
                item_details.setName("Others");
                item_details.setImageNumber(6);
                results.add(item_details);


            }

        }
    );

}



@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.test1101, menu);
    return true;
}
```

}

ItemListBasedapter.java:

```
package com.example.test1101;



public class ItemListBaseAdapter extends BaseAdapter {

private static ArrayList<ItemDetails> itemDetailsrrayList;
int[] color_arr={Color.MAGENTA,Color.DKGRAY,Color.BLACK,Color.CYAN,Color.GREEN,Color.GRAY};


private Integer[] imgid = {
        R.drawable.bb6,
        R.drawable.p1,
        R.drawable.bb5,
        R.drawable.bb2,
        R.drawable.p2,
        R.drawable.d1
        };

private LayoutInflater l_Inflater;

public ItemListBaseAdapter(Context context, ArrayList<ItemDetails> results) {
    itemDetailsrrayList = results;
    l_Inflater = LayoutInflater.from(context);
}

@Override
public int getCount() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return itemDetailsrrayList.size();
}

@Override
public Object getItem(int arg0) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return itemDetailsrrayList.size();
}

@Override
public long getItemId(int position) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return position;
}

@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent){
ViewHolder holder;



if (convertView == null) {
    convertView = l_Inflater.inflate(R.layout.list_view, null);
    holder = new ViewHolder();
    holder.txt_itemName = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.name);
    holder.itemImage = (ImageView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.photo);


    convertView.setTag(holder);
} else {
    holder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
}

holder.txt_itemName.setText(itemDetailsrrayList.get(position).getName());
holder.itemImage.setImageResource(imgid[itemDetailsrrayList.get(position).getImageNumber() - 1]);
convertView.setBackgroundColor(color_arr[position]);
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return convertView;
}

static class ViewHolder {
    TextView txt_itemName;
    ImageView itemImage;
}
```

}

Answer (score 0):

You need to set the adapter for the `ListView` for it to have the content.

At the end of `onClick` in your activity, do the following:

```
// I used getApplicationContext() here, but since you declared an attribute 
// called "context" and assigned the value as the activity, you could use 
// "Test1101.this.context" instead of "Test1101.this.getApplicationContext()".
ItemListBaseAdapter adapter = new ItemListBaseAdapter (Test1101.this.getApplicationContext(), results);
lv.setAdapter(adapter);
dialog.show ();
```

EDIT:
also realized, you haven't called `dialog.show ()`, so I've added that to the end of the code snippet above

Answer (score 0):

Two options off the top of my head:

1. Use AlertDialog.Builder and call [`setSingleChoiceItems()`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/AlertDialog.Builder.html#setSingleChoiceItems%28android.widget.ListAdapter,%20int,%20android.content.DialogInterface.OnClickListener%29), giving it your adapter.
2. Make a class extending [`DialogFrament`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/DialogFragment.html). Override `onCreateView()` and inflate a layout with a ListView. Set the adapter of the ListView and set an onListItemClick listener as you normally would in an Activity or Fragment.